# Latex to HTML with Pandoc, how do I include the Lua script output to the conversion?

Tags: lua, latex, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert LaTeX to HTML. However, I have a lua script included in the latex file (which pulls some data from a JSON file and formats the data to LaTeX). As I convert to HTML, the script is not executed but appears as lua in the output.

Is there either a way to get a pure latex output for the conversion or to run the script during the conversion?

Comment: You're not saying what your script is nor how you run it... but maybe you want to read https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html ?

Comment: Sorry, my first question and it is not easy to formulate a complete question. I use the TexStudio editor to compile, and the lua script is embedded between \begin{luacode} \end{luacode} commands (so not a separate lua file). Thanks for the link, I got to check that out, and see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: AFAIK TeXStudio only runs LaTeX directly, not pandoc. Maybe see https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html and https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness. I already know how generate the .html from .tex file in the command line with pandoc, if I have pure .tex input (without lua script). So, I guess I'm looking for a way to compile the lua script parts to pure tex, then I can convert it to HTML. If that makes sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "yes, but actually: no".

What I mean is that you *can* run the Lua code, but it is very likely to contain code which is luatex specific and will not work in pandoc.

Let's look at an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
You are runnig:
\begin{luacode}
tex.print(_VERSION)
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

The script, when run through `lualatex`, will report the Lua version used to execute the code (currently "Lua 5.3"). The `tex.print` command is provided by lualatex.

To see how pandoc handles this, we can convert it into pandoc's internal format with `pandoc --to=native`. Pandoc doesn't know the `luacode` environment, so it treats it like normal text.

```hs
[Para [Str "You",Space,Str "are",Space,Str "runnig:"]
,Div ("",["luacode"],[])
 [Para [Str "tex.print(_VERSION)"]]]
```

We see that the block becomes a div with class `luacode`. It's possible to run a Lua filter and execute it's content:

```lua
-- file: run-luacode.lua
function Div(d)
  local code = pandoc.utils.stringify(d)
  load(code)()
end
```

Using this with

```
pandoc my-test.latex --to=html --lua-filter=run-luacode.lua
```

Will lead to an error, because `tex.print` is undefined in pandoc's Lua.

```
Error running filter run-luacode.lua:
[string "tex.print(_VERSION)"]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'tex')
stack traceback:
        [string "tex.print(_VERSION)"]:1: in main chunk
        run-luacode.lua:3: in function 'Div'
```

Of course, we could define `tex.print` in the pandoc filter. E.g., setting

```lua
tex = {['print'] = print}
```

will at least print the result to the console. You could devise a mechanism that actually converts it to pandoc's internal document format. See https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html for details.

It might also be beneficial to call pandoc with `--from=latex+raw_tex`, which makes pandoc keep the unknown `luacode` environment verbatim in a `RawBlock` element. This can be easier to process in the filter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After some thought I think it is probably better for me to create a separate tex template file with a lua script with selected data elements, and then customize it in tex editor. So separate the lua from the tex file completely.